Fragment UI visible through other fragments after theme switch even though onDestroyView() is called
This is a strange one. I have a standard application using tab navigation with one MainActivity and four Fragments that are swapped whenever a user clicks on a bottom tab.
Here's how the Fragments are swapped:
val appointmentsFragment = AppointmentsFragment()                                            
val chatFragment = ChatFragment()                                                            
val journalFragment = JournalFragment()                                                      
val profileFragment = ProfileFragment()                                                      
lateinit var selectedFragment: Fragment                                                      
                                                                                             
if (savedInstanceState == null) {                                                            
    supportFragmentManager.commit {                                                          
        setReorderingAllowed(true)                                                           
        add(R.id.fragmentContainer, appointmentsFragment, appointmentsFragment.javaClass.simpleName)
        selectedFragment = appointmentsFragment                                              
    }                                                                                        
}                                                                                            
                                                                                             
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {                                       
    val selection = when(it.itemId) {                                                        
        R.id.appointments -> appointmentsFragment                                            
        R.id.chat -> chatFragment                                                            
        R.id.journal -> journalFragment                                                      
        R.id.profile -> profileFragment                                                      
        else -> { throw IllegalStateException("There are only 4 tabs.") }                    
    }                                                                                        
                                                                                             
    supportFragmentManager.commit {                                                          
        setReorderingAllowed(true)                                                           
        // Detach previous fragment                                                          
        detach(selectedFragment)                                                             
                                                                                                      
        val tag = selection.javaClass.simpleName                                             
        if (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {                         
            add(R.id.fragmentContainer, selection, tag)                                      
        } else {                                                                             
            attach(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)!!)                          
        }                                                                                    
        selectedFragment = selection                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                                                           
    true
}                                                                                     

Pretty standard stuff. The issue occurs when the following is performed:

Launch app as normal.
Background app and switch to settings, and enable or disable "Dark theme" mode.
Switch back to app, switch tabs if needed
Observe the corrupted UI

Here are some screenshots showing what occurs after performing those steps (click for larger photo):



As you can see, the UI of the other Fragments is, somehow, still on the screen, even though the Fragments containing those portions of UI were all detached. Additionally, I have confirmed that onDestroyView() is called for all of those old Fragments, which makes how or why their UI is still visible even more puzzling. It should also be said that when the theme is switched, and the user switches back to the app, the onDestroy of the MainActivity is called anyway, which I believe is standard.
Why is this issue occurring, and how can it be fixed? Thank you!

Do not keep fragment Instance . Create new instance everytime and use replace transaction instead of add .. If you are worried about data being lost there r lots of ways to handle that .. Using ViewModel  is a preferred one ..

Your selectedFragment is the cause, the one you detach on OnNavigationItemSelected is not match with previous one.
Because your fragment instance each time your activity recreate when rotated or theme changed:
val appointmentsFragment = AppointmentsFragment()                                            
val chatFragment = ChatFragment()                                                            
val journalFragment = JournalFragment()                                                      
val profileFragment = ProfileFragment()  

Check this
Better way I think is to create a registry for tab item-id and fragments, and their factory:
// A simple registry for tab item id to fragment tag, and it's factory.
// Fragment instance will only create when you call that factory.
private val fragmentRegistry: Map<Int, Pair<String, () -> Fragment>> = hashMapOf(
    R.id.appointments to (AppointmentsFragment::class.simpleName!! to { AppointmentsFragment() }),
    R.id.chat to (ChatFragment::class.simpleName!! to { ChatFragment() }),
    R.id.journal to (JournalFragment::class.simpleName!! to { JournalFragment() }),
    R.id.profile to (ProfileFragment::class.simpleName!! to { ProfileFragment() })
)

Then just show the selected fragment, and hide others:
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    // Get selected fragment registry, return or throw exception is ok when null.
    val itemId = it.itemId
    val (tag, factory) = fragmentRegistry[itemId] ?: return
    // Show the one selected
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
        var fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)
        if (fragment != null) {
            show(fragment).setMaxLifecycle(fragment, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
        } else {
            fragment = factory.invoke()
            add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, tag)
        }
    }.commit()
    // Hide the others
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
        fragmentRegistry.filterKeys { key -> key != itemId }.values.forEach { value ->
            val tagToHide = value.first
            val fragmentToHide =
                supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tagToHide) ?: return@forEach
            hide(fragmentToHide).setMaxLifecycle(
                fragmentToHide,
                Lifecycle.State.STARTED
            )
        }
    }.commit()
}

Note this way we don't need to handle with savedInstanceState.
This is show/hide approach, it will take more memory but avoid view re-create and flicker.
You can replace show/hide with attach/detach, and
attach/detach approach will take less memory but will re-create view.
It's up to you.
Hope it helps, have fun.
